# Criar aplicação para dois perfis diferentes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação que tem dois diferentes tipos de perfis e quero encontrar a melhor forma de estruturar minha aplicação sendo que:

1. Todas URLs do meu app vão iniciar com um dos dois perfis. Ex.: (root/pessoa_fisica, root/pessoa_juridica);
2. Muitas ações/telas serão compartilhadas pelos dois perfis, e algumas dessas telas terão comportamentos diferenciados para cada perfil, porém em outras não terão diferenças. (Ex.: root/perfil/about, root/perfil/contact_form);
3. Terei arquivos que serão renderizados em todas as telas de um perfil, e outros arquivos no outro perfil. (Ex.: header_pessoa_fisica, header_pessoa_juridica);

Alguém tem alguma dica para indicar?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi: Um usuário do sistema poderá ser cadastrado como PF ou PJ, e usará rotas diferentes de acordo com o tipo de pessoa. É isso? Ou todos os usuários terão acesso à todas as rotas?

Comment: Para algumas páginas estáticas, todos usuários tem acesso em ambas rotas, mesmo quando não estão cadastrados. Porém algumas páginas são apenas para usuários logados e de determinado perfil.

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que você tenha na sua tabela `usuarios` uma coluna chamada `tipo_pessoa`, que aceita os valores `F` ou `J`.

Se você quiser restringir todas as ações de um controlador para um ou outro tipo de pessoa, faça assim:

```
class MeuController < ApplicationController
  before_action :somente_pessoa_fisica

  private
    def somente_pessoa_fisica
      redirect_to root_path if current_usuario.tipo_pessoa === "J"
    end
end
```

O evento acima vai redirecionar o usuário para o root se ele for do tipo pessoa jurídica.

Se você quiser pode restringir a verificação para apenas ou exceto alguns métodos:

```
before_action :somente_pessoa_juridica, only: [:new, :create] # apenas new e create
before_action :somente_pessoa_juridica, except: [:new, :create] # exceto new e create
```

---

Para as rotas, o que você procura é o [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

```
namespace :pessoa_fisica do
  resources :foo
end

namespace :pessoa_juridica do
  resources :bar
end
```

Porém se um controlador deve estar acessível em mais de um namespace, não sei se vai funcionar. Eu preferiria não usar, acho melhor apenas filtrar com `before_action` como mostrei acima.

Comment: O problema é que eu realmente preciso que alguns controladores sejam comum à ambos tipos de pessoa

Comment: @RubyJuniorDev E o `before_action` não resolve seu problema? Você pode permitir para todos também, basta não usá-lo naquele controlador específico.

Comment: eu ainda preciso acessar as funcionalidades padrões sempre dentro ou da pessoa física ou da pessoa jurídica...

Comment: @RubyJuniorDev Não estou conseguindo te entender...

Comment: o que eu queria era ter o controlador AboutController, por exemplo, e acessar ele tanto com /pf/about quanto com /pj/about. Mas já resolvi fazer de outra forma que atendia minha necessidade original. Obrigado

Comment: @RubyJuniorDev Se alguma outra solução te atendeu, ***não*** aceite minha resposta como correta. Ao invés disso, crie uma resposta com a solução e aceite-a como correta.